# Lose 2 rep for participating in "extended conversation" or non-useful edit?

Tags: support

Yesterday I lost 2 rep for no apparent reason on SO. I hadn't reached my max and there are no downvotes visible. The only two potential causes I can think of are:

1. I suggested an edit that was not accepted;
2. I commented to somebody despite SO's "extended conversation" warning.

Can either of these things cause one to lose 2 rep? I don't care about the points, I'm just curious about the anomalous behavior.

Comment: You do *not* loose rep for the suggestion to move the conversation to chat. Check the `show removed posts` checkbox at the bottom of your reputation tab to see if a post was deleted, most likely a post you suggested an edit for was removed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out. The question was, do you lose rep for *commenting despite* the suggestion to move the conversation to chat?

Comment: No, you do not loose rep for commenting. The suggestion is just that, a suggestion.

Comment: I don't think you ever loose rep, but you might lose it. ;)

Comment: @nickb: Good thing I don't lose too much sleep over that recurring spelling mistake of mine. :-P

Comment: A [post you edited](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1874744) was deleted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither of those actions will lose you rep.

Actions that could lose you two rep:

1. Downvoting two answers.
2. Unaccepting an answer to a question of yours.
3. Having a question of yours deleted when there were no votes, but you had accepted an answer (thus losing the 2 rep for accepting an answer).
4. Having an upvote removed by the person who gave it (but this would only apply if right on the rep-cap border and the original upvote only gave 2 rep.
5. A post that you suggested an edit for was deleted.
6. You were downvoted (added for completeness, I know you said you weren't).
7. There was a rep re-calc; you had two too much rep before and this was compensating.

Comment: I believe the #5 is the case in this scenario, as pointed out by Flexo: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1874744